"Recursion limit" when trying to use chain with "llm.bind_tools"
I'm trying to get comfortable with LangGraph in an attempt to then develop a chatbot based on this framework.
When trying to test the idea of a node in my chatbot, I found myself faced with this error.
Could somebody please help me understand what's wrong with my code, and how can I solve this problem?
I would be truly thankful!
The code:
from typing import Annotated, List
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_community.tools.tavily_search import TavilySearchResults
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, PromptTemplate
from langchain_core.messages import BaseMessage
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

from langgraph.graph import StateGraph, END
from langgraph.graph.message import add_messages
from langgraph.prebuilt import ToolNode, tools_condition

# Define AgentState class with the proper typing
class AgentState(TypedDict):
    messages: Annotated[List[BaseMessage], add_messages]
    query: str
    games: List[str]

# Initialize the tool and LLM
tool = TavilySearchResults(max_results=3)
tools = [tool]
llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0)
llm_with_tools = llm.bind_tools(tools)

# Define the function for the game title search
def game_title_search(state: AgentState):
    game_search_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template="""You are part of a chatbot that provides personalized video game recommendations based on user preferences. \n
    Your task is to search for video games that match the user query, using the Tavily API. \n
    Only return the titles of the games. \n
    The number of games to return is limited to 5. \n\n

    The results provided will look as follows (Python list): \n
    ['game_title_1', 'game_title_2', 'game_title_3', ...]

    User Query: {query}""",
    input_variables=["query"],
)
    game_search = game_search_prompt | llm_with_tools

    game_search_result = game_search.invoke({"query": state["query"]})

    return {"messages": [game_search_result]} # Also, I need to extract the game titles from the tool result and update the state attribute "games" - how can I do this?

# Build the graph
graph_builder = StateGraph(AgentState)
graph_builder.add_node("game_search", game_title_search)

tool_node = ToolNode(tools=[tool])
graph_builder.add_node("tools", tool_node)

graph_builder.add_conditional_edges(
    "game_search",
    tools_condition,
)

graph_builder.add_edge("tools", "game_search")
graph_builder.set_entry_point("game_search")
graph = graph_builder.compile()

# Define the initial state
input_state = {
    "messages": [],
    "query": "",
    "games": []
}

user_input = "What games are similar to The Witcher 3?"
input_state["query"] = user_input
input_state["messages"] = [("user", user_input)]

output = graph.invoke(input_state, config={"recursion_limit": 50})
print(output)


What I was expecting was for the LLM chain to return back a Python list of the video games' titles it fetched from the web-search operation, which was then supposed to be used in updating the state's attribute "games". But I can't even think of a way of implementing that until I find a solution to this problem of mine.
